# Am I properly running this AND query in mongoose properly because I am not getting anything

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the code, am I running the `.and` query properly?

```
const getUserMessages = async (id) => {
  const userMessages = await MessageCollection.find({}).and([{sentById: id}, {sentToId: id}]).sort({dateSent: 'ascending'})
  return userMessages
}
```

Comment: you try to get message that user send to himself? (sendById=id AND sendToId=id)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
const userMessages = await MessageCollection.find({sentById: id, sentToId: id}).sort({dateSent: 'ascending'})
```

By default, mongoose will apply an AND condition to every key in the query, unless you specify otherwise by using `$or` or some other special query parameter. The query above will find all Messages where `sentById = sentToId`